# build array of json object while looping array of data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `const A=['string1','string2','string3']`.

I want to achieve an object that has the following form:

```js
const images = [
  { url: "string1" },
  { url: "string2" },
  { url: "string3" }
];
```

This is what I've tried:

```js
const images = A.map((image) => {
  JSON.stringify({
    url: `/img/{image}`
  });
});
```

But the result is an array filled with `undefined` values.

Comment: The reason it is `undefined` is because when you have curly braces you have to return a value inorder for it to be saved on the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand why are you using `JSON.stringify()`?

The simplest solution:

```js
const images = A.map((image) => ({
  url: `/img/${image}`
}))
```

The `()` that are wrapping the implicit return are **mandatory** since we're directly returning an object.